# Lasso Selection Implementation

Tags: .net, math, graphics, intersection

[image]

I would like to implement something like autocad's lasso selection in 2D.Blue is full inclusion and green is partial (eg:if you select a part of a line). I am looking for a good enough algorithm to achieve this goal. Lasso selection is arbitary polygon (can be concave or convex or self intersecting) .
First it seems that I have to convert a polygon to convex or triangulate it. However for .net I found this [LibTessDotNet](https://github.com/speps/LibTessDotNet).
The problem with triangulation approach is that I cant figure out how to know if eg a line is contained fully because parts of the line can be at any polygon.
Other idea is to use a library like Clipper and determine via boolean operations the intersection. For full I would do difference (which should be empty) or intersection for partial.

Is there any better/working approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I had implemented Lasso selection for curves (such as lines, circles, partial circles, ellipses,...etc) using the "point in polygon" algorithm as following:

1) For a given curve, sample some points from it. 
2) For each sampled point, check if the point is within the polygon formed by the Lasso path. If more than two points are within the Lasso path, this curve is partially enclosed. If all sampled points are within the Lasso path, this curve is fully enclosed.

You can get the "point in polygon" algorithm and source codes from the internet such as in this link (http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/).

If you have many curves and start to worry about performance, then you can check if the bounding box of the curve has intersection with the bounding box of the Lasso path. If no, then you can skip this curve in the search. But doing this requires you to compute a bounding box for each curve before hand and you need to make sure it is up-to-date with any possible change to the curves.

Comment: This would work but I am not sure how precise it is.Autocad seems to not match full enclosure even  if you have 2-3 pixel gap  but point in polygon could easilly miss it. Also I dont get how to check with bounding box since 4 points of the rectangle may not intersect with lasso but lasso would with curve..

Comment: My original post about how to use bounding box to speed up search is incorrect. I got mixed up with a different but similar scenario. The post is edited.